# How to change values in a pandas DataFrame column based on a condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to change the value of my row where if the column "state" had the value of "CANCELLED" then it would change the row value from column "Activity" into "Cancelled"

It should be like this:

| ID | Activity | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | created | CANCELLED |
| 1 | completed | CANCELLED |
| 2 | created | FINNISHED |
| 2 | completed | FINISHED |
| 3 | created | REJECTED |
| 3 | rejected | REJECTED |

what i tired using `df.loc[df.state == "CANCELLED", "Activity"] = "cancelled"`

It did changed the Activity but i still wanted the created activity to be the same.

There's also an error

```
C:\Users\aldev\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1720: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_column(loc, value, pi)
```

If anyone has an answer thank you in advance

Comment: Are you saying that you only want some of the CANCELLED activies to change? "completed" should change but 'created" should not? Are there other conditions?

Comment: The error message is probably related to some code before the df.loc... line you are sharing, where you have something like df = df2. If you want to copy a dataframe you should write it explicitly like df = df2.copy()

Comment: Was that the full error message? They usually show the line in your code that failed.

Comment: This is a warning not an error.  You can read more about it in the link that is shown in the waning statement.  Also you can look it up `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes it is it should only change the 'completed' activity if the state is 'cancelled', and no there are no other conditions. it seem that i miss understood the warning there are no other errors just that warning

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[(df.state == "CANCELLED") & (df.Activity != "created"), "Activity"] = "cancelled"
```

The code was missed `()`, in the `(df.state == "CANCELLED")`

Answer (score 0):

We need to find the rows where the state = 'cancelled'. We can use the `.loc(row, column)` operator to select the entries where state = 'cancelled' and return the 'Activity' column we then just replace those values with 'cancelled'

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], "Activity": ['created', 'completed', 'created', 'completed', 'created',
                                               'rejected'], "state": ['cancelled', 'cancelled', 'finished', 'finished', 'rejected', 'rejected']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.loc[df['state'] == 'cancelled', 'Activity'] = 'cancelled'


print(df)
```

| ID | Activity | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cancelled | cancelled |
| 1 | cancelled | cancelled |
| 2 | created | finished |
| 2 | completed | finished |
| 3 | created | rejected |
| 3 | rejected | rejected |